# What axis should we consider in a double polarizer?

Tags: polarization

Q : Unpolarized light of intensity I passes through an ideal polarizer A. Another identical polarizer B is placed behind A. The intensity of light beyond B is found to be I/2. Now another identical polarizer C is placed between A and B. The intensity beyond B is now I/8 find  the angle between polarizer A and C :

[image]

This is the given solution. My doubt is whether we should apply an extra cos²(θ) beyond polarizer B since it is in phase with Polarizer A ( understood from the first part of the question).

Please note that polarizer C in placed IN BETWEEN not behind Polarizer B.

Comment: @EdV May I know the name of the software you used for the simulation.

Comment: @EdV Oh that's alright, I understood it anyway. And thanks for the upvote. :)